# Lead and lag with groupby condition

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For each `entity_id` in the signals dataset, find the `item_id` with the oldest and newest `month_id`.

In some cases it may be the same item. If there are 2 different items with the same `month_id` then take the item with the lower `item_id`.

Finally sum the count of signals for each entity and output as the `total_signals`. The correct output should contain 1 row per unique `entity_id`.

**Input:**

```
entity_id: long
item_id: integer
source: integer
month_id: integer
signal_count: integer
```

**Output:**

```
entity_id: long
oldest_item_id: integer
newest_item_id: integer
total_signals: integer
```

How can I use windowing functions lead and lag particular `month_id` column?

input:

### +---------+-------+------+--------+------------+

### |entity_id|item_id|source|month_id|signal_count|

### +---------+-------+------+--------+------------+

### | 359781| 20001| 21000| 201705| 1|

### | 359781| 20001| 21000| 201707| 1|

### | 359781| 3| 21000| 201708| 2|

### | 359781| 3| 21000| 201712| 2|

### | 359781| 3| 975| 201512| 4|

output:

### entity_id   oldest_item_id   newest_item_id  total_signals

### 359781         3                3               23

### 152813413      1000            1000              2

### 224619015        0               3              12

using scala api's and spark dataframe

Comment: Hi Suresh, welcome to SO! It is always helpful to post a sample of data you are processing and what have you attempted to achieve the result.

Comment: I want  two new columns oldest_item,newest_item based on item_id,month_id, If there are 2 different items with the same month_id then take the item with the lower item_id ,by using lead or lag it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use `lead()` and `lag()` for this.  You would use aggregation.  In this case, you need some conditional aggregation as well.

This might be the best approach:

```
select t.entity_id, t.num_signals,
       tmin.item_id as item_id_min_month,
       tmax.item_id as item_id_max_month
from (select t.entity_id, sum(signal_count) as num_signals,
             min(month_id) as min_month_id,
             max(month_id) as max_month_id
      from t
     ) t join
     t tmin
     on tmin.entity_id = t.entity_id and
        tmin.month_id = t.min_month_id join
     t tmax
     on tmax.entity_id = t.entity_id and
        tmax.month_id = t.max_month_id ;
```

You can also use `first_value()` and `last_value()` if those are available in your version of SparkSQL.

Comment: How can we implement using scala api's and dataframes? Please help me